# Facebook Graph API - Page Public Content Access

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, screencast, facebook-app-settings

I have created an App that fetches latest post data (images and text) from public Facebook page and display on my website. I have submitted my application for review but it has been rejected. I have seen examples and documents and everything requires a user login, but my API does not need login.

The user can click on the title of the page and the user goes to facebook.

"Feedback From Your Last Submission (6/28, 11:18pm)
Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually.
All permissions data must be visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later.
Please see our Examples page to learn more about making and submitting a successful screencast.
Learn more about testing permissions prior to approval."

Can anyone help me with this, how should I take a screencast? I dont know how to solve this issue, as my App does not violates any security rule still my Graph API rejected.

---

I was using graph API and this "pagename?fields=picture" to get the access tokken and the extended it to 2 months and placed it in the below function;

```
function get_facebook_post_pic_full_url($feed_id)
{   
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $feed_id . "' );</script>";  
    $ursls = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$feed_id.'/?fields=full_picture,picture&access_token="Access Tokken"';
    $fb_act = json_decode(file_get_contents($ursls));
    return $fb_act;
}
```

And the below code is used to fetch and display image and caption and date;

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 no-padding">
<div class="facebook_img">
  <?php
  $fb_feeds = get_facebook_page_feed();

  if(!empty($fb_feeds)):

        $feeds = $fb_feeds->data[0];
        $created_time = $feeds->created_time;
        $link = $feeds->link;
        $feed_id = $feeds->id;

        $full_arr = get_facebook_post_pic_full_url($feed_id);

        $full_picture = $full_arr->full_picture;
        $message = $feeds->message;
        $submessage = substr($message,0,75);

    ?>
    <!--<?php  var_dump($full_arr);?> -->
  <img style="width:405px;height:341px" src="<?php echo $full_picture; ?>" alt="facebook"/>
  <div class="fb_content"> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $submessage; ?></a>
    <dt><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($created_time)); ?></dt>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

$feed_id is correct for sure. But the images or the post are not displaying anymore. I am not sure whether I need my App for review or not. :/
If anyone have steps to do that please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Also to apply for review I have no idea which persmissions should I use.

Comment: _“and display on my website”_ - show them that – at least. Plus, if you got any sort of backend where these posts are shown, probably show that as well. And be very very clear in your review instructions, what the purpose of this app is and who it is going to be used by.

Comment: _“as my App does not violates any security rule”_ - that doesn’t necessarily mean that Facebook still wants you to be able to do what it does … Displaying content from your own pages would be one thing – but from public pages, is another.

Comment: publishing content from a page you do not manage on some other website...i am not sure if facebok wants that, or if the admins of the page want that...in fact, i would not want any website to publish content from my pages without my permission. just saying.

Comment: I am trying to fetch information from my page on my website. I think I was not clear about in my App review application. I will give it a try again. I hope it gets approved this time. Thank you

Comment: @sundasmunir were you able to get the Page Public Content Access permission in your app?

Comment: @Criesto Thanks for asking. But I am sending my app for review today, didn't get the time before.

Comment: @CBroe You have mentioned to show backend, but we are not supposed to show any code in the sceencast, so I am not sure how it can be done :/

Comment: What does showing the back end where you perhaps manage those posts or something like that, have to do with showing code?

Comment: That's my confusion as well. I am not managing anything from the website. I am just fetching public post data from my facebook page to my website. Users can not like the page from website and they can not enter the app from website. The app just fetches data from facebook page to be displayed to website visitors using graph API. I am not sure what to submit and what to show in screencast. I have youtube, Google+, Instagram and Twitter feeds working in the same way. My facebook grid is black, Lolz

Comment: Hi @sundasmunir did you solve your problem? I am having same problems with exactly use cases like yours

Comment: @tasqyn apologies for the delay in reply. Yes, the issue was sorted. Please explain the problem that you are facing, may be I can help you.

Comment: @sundasmunir thanks for the reply. We want to show our facebook pages posts on our website but for this Public Page Content Access facebook wants to show us login button but we don't need it. We want only show posts that's it.

Comment: No that should be not be the case. My issue was solved by trying different endpoints. The access tokken gets expired after 2 months which I am renewing after 2 months but the posts are working fine. Please let me know which end point you are using and how are you fectching and displaying data?

Comment: @tasqyn Is your problem solved? :) Please let me know if any help is required.

Comment: @sundasmunir thanks. I've solved my problem. There was no need for Public Page Content Access, as you said we had to renew it.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to access only a Facebook page you own you don't need to go through a review, simply use Roles in the Settings.

[Facebook review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Its getting confusing for me. Now I am not sure whether I need app review or not. I have visited the link and read through it and it seems the permission is not required for what I am trying to achieve. But still my feed are not being displayed. :/

Comment: Do you have admin access to both the website and the Facebook page? If so, you should create the Facebook app as usual. Given that you don't want others to access your Facebook app there is no need to make it public, therefore no review is needed. Simply add the Facebook user you intend in using when connecting your website with FB as a Tester in the Roles menu on your app Settings.

Comment: One more question is the full_picture parameter working for pages? I am sorry for asking so many questions.